# How to setParam xmlrpc value struct with C++?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have getParam() working. The initial data  is loaded from a configuration yaml from my launch file.

I am trying to figure out how to write a C++ structure out using setParam() to update the same data.

What do I create in C++ in order to call setParam() and store the data in the parameter server?

Here is an example of the yaml:

```
drive_config:
  mode: mecanum
  radius: 0.062
  rpm: 60.0
  scale: 1.0
  track: 0.2
  servos:
    - {servo: 1, position: 1}
    - {servo: 2, position: 2}
    - {servo: 3, position: 3}
    - {servo: 4, position: 4}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252375/how-to-setparam-xmlrpc-value-struct-with-c++-?/) by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 300 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:\

> (I'll edit this again once I figure out how to include formatted code)

select the text, press `ctrl+k` or click the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-19**:
re: (I'll edit this again once I figure out how to include formatted code)

I was on a mobile device. The 101010 button did not do it correctly. Thanks for fixing my question.

**Comment by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on 2019-06-22**:
is there any easy to set the .xml file to rosserver???   Must I re-write the contents of my .yaml in c++ code to build the xmlrpc as above??? xmlrpc can not load .xml or .yaml directly?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have encountered the exact same problem today and the solution was not a straightforward one. Unfortunately XmlRpc API does not have a dedicated method for the custom structs. Therefore, you need to write your own function that validly constructs an XML from your struct.

Following code constructs a valid portion of your yaml file which affects the parameter server in the exact same manner as yaml file would.

```
const string init_value = "<value>";
const string end_value = "</value>";
const string init_struct = "<struct>";
const string end_struct = "</struct>";
```

There are also `<data>`, `<array>` and `<member>` tags. They should be defined as above. Then for only the `mode` part:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue drive_config;
string xml_body;
xml_body.append(init_value);
xml_body.append(init_struct);
xml_body.append(init_member);
xml_body.append("<name>mode</name>");
xml_body.append(init_value);
xml_body.append("mecanum");
xml_body.append(end_value);
xml_body.append(end_member);
xml_body.append(end_struct);
xml_body.append(end_value);

int offset = 0;
int* offset_ptr = &offset;
drive_config.fromXml(xml_body,offset_ptr);
nh.setParam("/drive_config",drive_config);
```

Above lines will upload a parameter to ROS Parameter Server in the form of:

```
drive_config:
    mode: mecanum
```

Above code can be optimized, automated and shortened with struct tag retrievals, type resolvers and recursive calls. But for the current task, naïve implementation would suffice.

I recommend first printing the raw XML format of a known parameter uploaded through YAML file. Then, it will be easier to construct arrays of arrays, arrays of dicts, dicts of arrays and etc.

---

Originally posted by [tahsinkose](https://answers.ros.org/users/31285/tahsinkose/) with karma: 46 on 2018-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a way:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue a;
a.setSize(2);
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 1;
ros::param::set("param_name", a);
```

Just keep nesting this and you can set any parameter structure you want.

---

Originally posted by [mihota](https://answers.ros.org/users/3807/mihota/) with karma: 13 on 2019-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2021-01-23**:
this works for modifying the retrieved data and can then be used to set a param on the server as was the question!

**Comment by [luckyyou](https://answers.ros.org/users/68784/luckyyou/) on 2021-02-04**:
Thank you so much. You can even do

```
a["name"] = 3;
```

and skip the setSize. Awesome.